# Add dummy nodes prior to apply template (cals table with variant entry nodes count)

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am transforming a CALS table and the row parent nodes may host different entry nodes count. I am looking at "equalizing" the node count before I apply the template in order to stay coherent.
Otherwise i guess I can call a template on purpose but it seems clunky.
Say CALS row data where:

```html
<row>
  <entry>a</entry>
  <entry>b</entry>
</row>
<row>
  <entry>1</entry>
  <entry>2</entry>
  <entry>3</entry>
  <entry>4</entry>
</row>
```

And in the end I need

```html
<Cell … >a</Cell>
<Cell … >b</Cell>
<Cell … ></Cell>
<Cell … ></Cell>
<Cell … >1</Cell>
<Cell … >2</Cell>
<Cell … >3</Cell>
<Cell … >4</Cell>
```

So I am looking to add two dummy "entry" node so they will be equally transformed by the template.

```html
<xsl:apply-template select="entry"/>
```

Am I clear enough ?

TIA Loic

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is how to determine the max amount of `entry`'s in one `row`, right?

In XPath 3.1 (XSLT 2.0) you could use something like `max(//row/entry[last()]/count(preceding-sibling::*))+1`. But you tagged your question "xslt-1.0", so you would have to write a `max` template yourself. Or use a completely different approach.

Comment: thanks to both of you. I ended up with using a recursive template. Both of you are right, a max parameter is required and is the computation of a column count minus an row/entries count.

Comment: @Loic please consider to select and/or upvote if your question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 1.0 you may try.
Create a variable with max entries:

```
<xsl:variable name="maxentries">
    <xsl:for-each select="//row" >
        <xsl:sort select="count(entry)" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(entry)"  />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

A template to create `cnt` empty "Cells":

```
<xsl:template name="emptyCell">
    <xsl:param name="cnt"/>
    <xsl:if test ="$cnt > 0">
        <Cell/>
        <xsl:call-template name="emptyCell">
            <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="$cnt - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

An use for example like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry" />
        <xsl:call-template name="emptyCell">
            <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="$maxentries - count(entry)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```